# A surprising results with a interesting inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math

let $x,y,z>0$ such $x+y+z=3$, Find the minimum of the value
$$F=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{xy}+\dfrac{1}{xyz}$$

I use wolfapha found  the surprising results $F_{min}=\dfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

see [links](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%281%2Fx%2B1%2Fxy%2B1%2F%28xy%283-x-y%29%29%29%2C)

maybe use AM-GM inequality,but I can't it,so How to prove $F\ge\dfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

The question came from a middle school exam (14 age ago)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @HansEngler,How to prove $F\ge\dfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: Lagrange's Multiplier should be sufficient...

Comment: maybe have without Lagrange's Multiplier methods

Comment: @inequality if you intend to impose conditions, clearly state them in the post body.  And don’t move the goalposts if someone uses a solution which you forgot to exclude with conditions .

Comment: To clarify, are you allowed to use basic derivatives? IE is the competition aimed at those aged 14, or aged 18? (Not sure whether "14 age ago" means that the exam was 14 years ago, or for those aged 14)

Answer (score 1):

If we allow for 1-variable calculus, then

1. Fix $y+z = k$. Show that the minimum of $\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{yz} = \frac{z+1}{z(k-z) } $ subject to $ y> 0, z> 0$ has value

> $\frac{1}{ (\sqrt{k+1} -1 ) ^2 }$ and occurs at $z = \sqrt{k+1} - 1$.

2. So $ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{xy} + \frac{1}{xyz}  = \frac{1}{x} ( 1 + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{yz} ) \geq \frac{1}{3-k} ( 1 + \text{ answer from above } ) $. We can verify that the minimum occurs at $ k = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, and has value $\frac{ 3 + \sqrt{5} } { 2}$.